# Can't publish colleagues ASP.NET web application to a web server

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2010

My colleague and I are both using VS 2010 and we have created a web application each. We can both publish our own applications to a ftp (web host's) and it works fine. However, if my colleague send me his solution and I run it locally on my machine it works but when I try to publish it I get promped for password and I enter it (same as I use for my application) but it fails. Same for my colleague if he takes a copy of my solution and tries to publish it. He can publish his own solution though.

What can be the issue here? We know we use the same login and password for the ftp and we can both log on to the ftp with the login and password when using a ftp client. Is there some setting that we need to set to allow other machines than the one the application was developed on to be able to publish projects?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Any error messages or anything?

Comment: Incorrect password, but I use the same for my application and my colleague use the same when he is publishing his application.

Answer (score 0):

Are you publishing to the same place as your colleague? I know that VS 2010 saves a publish profile (maybe you are using your colleague's profile (some other location), with your password)?

Comment: Yeah same place. He created an application, sent it to me, I made some changes and sent it back and then he couldn't publish it. But if he overwrite the Publish.xml from my copy with his original solution he can now publish it again but I can't. Where is the password in the publish.xml file taken from?

Comment: The password is stored in the publish XML file when you first setup the profile.  You can even tell it, at that time, not to store a password, but ask the user instead.  If I were you, I would look at both publish XML files to see if there are any differences. Mainly at the first line, though.  That's where the profile information is stored.